# Edit text styling android

Tags: android, android-styles

How to style an edit text like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5C538.jpg)?

The lock is an icon. how to insert the bar after the lock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a single icon of lock and bar and use `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_icon"`

EXAMPLE:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="as_Your_Need"
        android:layout_height="as_Your_Need"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_back"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_icon"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences"
        android:textSize="as_Your_Need" />
```

You can Make background of edittext with a image contains lock and bar